# Woocommerce: only allow products from one tag per transaction

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce site with the Responsive Supermarket Online Theme - Oswad installed. Each product has one of 4 tags corresponding to a different vendor. What I need to do when adding to cart:

1. Check the cart for products and get their tag.
2. If cart is empty, or the product tags match, allow adding to cart as per normal.
3. If the product has a different tag then that of the cart contents, disable the add to cart button.
4. Steps 1-3 should only occur once per transaction.

I know that I can check the tag with  `if ( has_term( 'tag', 'product_tag') )`,

and in the add-to-cart.php, `$product->isPurchasable()` will toggle the visibility of the button.

My stumbling block is finding out how to put all these together to fulfill the requirement. I tried looking for how to restrict the cart items by categories but came up with dead ends. I looked for plugins but those restricted only the minimum/maximum product per order and not checking the category/tags of the items. I even tried to look at the hooks but ended up getting more confused.

Would appreciate it if I could get a pointer in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution - at the add-to-cart.php:

```
global $woocommerce, $product;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_tag');

$items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

foreach($items as $item => $values){
    $_product = $values["data"];
    $_terms = wp_get_post_terms($_product->id, 'product_tag');
    //echo "product slug: " . $terms[0]->slug;
    //echo "cart slug: " . $_terms[0]->slug;
    if ($terms[0]->slug !== $_terms[0]->slug){
        //echo "NO MATCH";
        $match = false;
    }
}
```

and then add a `if ($match)` statement controlling the add to cart button: `apply_filters('woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', ...`

Also, add the code to woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/simple.php and add the if statement to the location of the add to cart button.